# kendo ui Sparkline - how to change bar color

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I didn't manage to change the color of the line .
By default, it's orange ...

https://jsfiddle.net/z7xo8thx/

```
$("#temp-range").kendoSparkline({
    type: "bullet",
    data: [21, 23],
    valueAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 50,
    plotBands: [{
      from: 0,
      to: 15,
      color: "#787878",
      opacity: 0.15
    },  {
    from: 16,
    to: 50,
    color: "#787878",
    opacity: 0.15
  }]
},
tooltip: {
  visible: true
}
});
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you try to change the Theme?  I updated your fiddle by adding `theme:"black"` https://jsfiddle.net/z7xo8thx/1/ .. You have many options to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the seriesColors property:

```
seriesColors: ["#558B9B"],
```

Updated **[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/z7xo8thx/2/)**

Comment: Do you know how to change the color of the vertical red line in the chart?